# trouble starting nginx on Debian9

Tags: debian, nginx

I have installed nginx-full on debian9 and I cant start it.
When I did.

`sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start`

I got

```
[....] Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

I also tried
`sudo nginx -t`
and got

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

the output for the systemctl status nginx.service is:

```
$sudo systemctl status nginx.service

 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-06-06 15:16:04 IST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2305 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2302 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27844 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


Jun 06 15:16:02 debedx nginx[2305]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 06 15:16:02 debedx nginx[2305]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 06 15:16:03 debedx nginx[2305]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 06 15:16:03 debedx nginx[2305]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 06 15:16:04 debedx nginx[2305]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 06 15:16:04 debedx nginx[2305]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jun 06 15:16:04 debedx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 06 15:16:04 debedx systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jun 06 15:16:04 debedx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 06 15:16:04 debedx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please add output from `systemctl status nginx.service`

Comment: The correct way to ask your question should describe how you install `nginx` and with proper log as suggested by Mikael can you please [edit] your question to add a bit more information ? Also take the time to read the [tour] it will help you understand how this community work and how you can improve your question.

Comment: what about `systemctl restart nginx.service` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of `systemctl status nginx.service`, it seems that the port on which nginx is running is being used by other process.

You can check that using `netstat -tulpn|grep 80` command. Once identified,

(1) Either change the port no. of `nginx` in it's configuration file by editing `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` using an editor and set `'Listen <new_port_no.>'`and start `nginx` (`systemctl start nginx.service`) or

(2) Kill that process if that process is not significant by issuing command and the start `nginx`. To know process id of the process, type: `ps aux|grep <process name>`

```
kill <process id>
```

Make sure what you are going to do before killing the process. Hence I would suggest you to change the port no. of `nginx`